# Java subproject depedency in kotlin gradle project doensn't work in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have an issue when trying to use other service as dependency when it is in java but project is in kotlin.

```
Structure:
--lib(java)
--java-service
--kotlin-service
```

In Intellij when in java-service add lib dependency everything works fine. I can use classes when autocomplete. But when I try to use lib classes in kotlin-service I have to manually add imports, set class fields manually etc. Autocomplete doesen't work. Code is compiling and run properly.

I add dependency as :
`implementation project(":lib")`

What should I do to use autocomplete.

[Imports from dependency project in java when main project is in kotlin doesn't work](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221055?project=IDEA&clearDraft=true&description=IU-192.5728.98,%20JRE%2011.0.3%2012-b304.10x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o,%20OS%20Linux(amd64)%20v5.0.0-23-generic,%20screens%202560x1440,%201366x768)

Comment: `implementation project(:"lib")` is invalid syntax, did you mean `implementation project(":lib")`?

Comment: Is the issue only in auto-completion? When you add import - do you see "red" unresolved code or it is resolved in Editor and you can navigate to declaration?

Comment: Also there is Red unresolved deckaration which cannot be navigated